# How to see few fields in the view but later clicking on the record should show all fields?

Tags: sapui5, hana

My HANA table consists of 20 fields but I want my view to display only 5 fields for each record in my browser through an xml view. But again, when I click on the particular row on browser, I should be able to see all 20 field for that record. How will that be possible?

Comment: So you have a table with 5 columns, and only for the selected table row you want to display 20 columns? I wonder what your UI design looks like

Answer (score 0):

That's the classic master detail pattern, and can be solved quite nicely.

In your master view, you can set the binding of your table to the OData entity set as per usual, but to limit the number of fields being transferred, you should use the `select` parameter:

```
    items="{
        path: '/AwesomeStuff',
        parameters: {
            select: 'Id,Name'
        }
    }"
```

The `press` event of your `ColumnListItem` in the table should be implemented and in that event handler it would be nicest to use the router and navigate to e.g. path `/AwesomeStuff/12345`.

In your detail view, you'll have to create a handler that responds to something that happens in the master, e.g. navigation. You could do this by binding an event handler to the router in the detail view, e.g.:

```
this.getRouter().getRoute("AwesomeStuff").attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
```

In the implementation of the `onRouteMatched` handler, bind the detail view to the full set of record data by:

```
this.getView().bindElement({
        path: this.getModel().createKey(
            "/AwesomeStuff", 
            { Id: oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Id })
    }});
```

The `bindElement` method binds the (detail) view to a single OData element (not a list). If this element is cached in the ODataModel, it will be re-used. But if it's not in cache, a request is made to the server. Note that you can leave the `select` parameter away from this call, as you want the full set of data in your detail view, which is the default.

If you're looking for some code samples, generate a new project from the "SAP Fiori Master-Detail Application" template in SAP WebIDE.

Comment: I am new to UI5...could you please elaborate?

Comment: That was a quite elaborate answer already. Which part needs further clarification?

Comment: Unable to get data in detail view..details cntrlr code-onInit: function () {
   var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  
   oRouter.getRoute("home").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
  
  },
  _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
   var oArgs, oView;
   oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
   oView = this.getView();
   oView.bindElement({
     path: this.getModel().createKey(
                "/jobdetails", 
                { Id: oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Id })
   });
   console.log('id: ' + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Id);
  },